# <br> в форме отправки php

Tags: php, html

```
if (mail("example@gmail.com", "Заявка с сайта", "Имя: ".$name."E-mail: ".$email."Телефон: ".$tel."Страна: ".$filesB. "Город: ".$town,  "From: info@verigin.info \r\n"))
 {     echo "сообщение успешно отправлено";
} else {
    echo "при отправке сообщения возникли ошибки";
}?>
```

Всем привет, есть такое дело не понимаю как правильно сделать отступы между "Имя" "E-mail" и т.д.
То есть надо, чтобы все данные были с новой строки. В гугле забанили (честно пыталась искать), но ничего дельного не нашла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты можешь отправить html сообщение. На сайте php.net про это написано https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php Вот сам пример, который тебе нужен

```
<?php
// несколько получателей
$to = 'johny@example.com, sally@example.com'; // обратите внимание на запятую

// тема письма
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// текст письма
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Johny</td><td>10th</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// Для отправки HTML-письма должен быть установлен заголовок Content-type
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Дополнительные заголовки
$headers[] = 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>';
$headers[] = 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com';
$headers[] = 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com';

// Отправляем
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй \n должно помочь, но лучше создавать шаблоны:-)